# Acumatica Web Service Endpoint API

Tags: api, acumatica, endpoint

I am trying to use Postman to get data from the Acumatica Contact endpoint. I am doing this because I want to create a put and want to see the formatting of what is needed for the Contact Endpoint.

I have logged in successfully using the PUT method and I am using the GET method on this URL: http://localhost/entity/Default/17.200.001/Contact

However I am receiving this error when I push send:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:\r\nAddressValidated: View AddressCurrent has BQL delegate\r\n",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.CannotOptimizeException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.NotWorkingOptimizedExportProvider.get_CanOptimize()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetListImpl(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.GetList(String objectName, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Has anyone else got this/know how to get past it?

Comment: Which version of Acumatica are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to see the structure of the data, issue a `GET` to `entity/Default/17.200.001/Contact/{contactId}`, this way you'll be returned only one entity, which is both faster and does not require optimization.

Comment: If I'm going to be creating a PUT into Contact, do I have to create a ContactID or can one be automatically assigned?

Comment: That depends on how your Acumatica is configured. As far as I remember, Contact has its ID assigned automatically.