# Acumatica Rest API: Issue creating a Get Request using Delegates

Tags: acumatica

First, I created a very simple graph with one datamember:

```
    namespace DevSource
{
    public class EPTest : PXGraph<EPTest>
    {
        public PXSelect<Batch> BatchRecords;
    }
}
```

Then I created the endpoint and the Get request via Postman with successful result:
[Successful Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtCOB.png)

Then I added a delegate to that datamember:

```
        #region Delegates
    protected virtual IEnumerable batchRecords()
    {
        List<Batch> res = new List<Batch>();


        PXSelectBase<Batch> sel = new PXSelect<Batch>(this);

        foreach (PXResult<Batch> it in sel.Select())
        {
            Batch local = (Batch)it;
            if (local.BatchNbr != null && local.BatchNbr != "AP000064")
            {
                res.Add(it);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    #endregion
```

The result is successful in Acumatica's UI, but the Get request gives the following error:
[Failed Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTAG2.png)

I am currently working with version 17.207.0029.

Do I have to configure something else during the endpoint creation? Am I missing a step?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, I updated the post. Thanks

Comment: Because it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to say what you have to configure.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev the example in the post was for reference only. Our project uses our own tables. I wanted to present a simple scenario with Batch table to show how the Get Request in Acumatica works properly with a direct dataview but fails with the use of a delegate (which is what is occurring in our system as well)

Comment: The reason for the "failure" is explicitly listed in the response, and this behavior is currently expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SergRogovtsev. Does that mean that Acumatica's API won't work with Graphs using dataview delegates?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You should be able to get a single entity from such a graph without any issue.

Comment: Thanks @SergRogovtsev. What could I be doing wrong? The error message states "Optimization cannot be performed" but I'm not doing any optimizations. The graph has nothing other than the Dataview and its delegate (I created it for testing purposes as my original graph presents the same error)

Comment: You are not, but the system tries to when you're getting _a list of entries from it_. Any view having delegate breaks such optimization, and such request is failed.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev is it possible to recover that optimization? Using this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237856/acumatica-web-service-endpoint-api we got one record at a time. Can we get a list of records instead?

Comment: If you have a delegate on primary view - no, it isn't possible. If your delegate is on some other view, you can get a list of entity selecting only the fields that are from views that do not have delegates.